# Is C++ function belonging to "callable type"

Tags: function, c++11, types, definition, callable

The C++11 standard says:

```
20.8.1 Definitions [func.def]
1 The following definitions apply to this Clause:
2 A call signature is the name of a return type followed by a parenthesized comma-separated list of zero or
more argument types.
3 A callable type is a function object type (20.8) or a pointer to member.
4 A callable object is an object of a callable type.
```

So my understanding is, a function is an instance of function type, so function is not "callable type". But definitely we can call functions.

This definition is a bit weird to me. Where did I get wrong?

Comment: where do you read that a function is an instance of function type? It says a callable type is a function object type and an object of this type is a callable type.

Comment: A function is not an object, so nothing in this clause applies to functions. A pointer-to-function type, on the other hand, is a function object type, and hence a callable type. A pointer-to-function is then a callable object. Further, thanks to *function-to-pointer conversion* **[conv.func]**, "function" and "pointer-to-function" are interchangeable for most practical purposes (but not necessarily for formal standardese).